# Delete dynamically created controls from the middle of a set

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Maybe I'm borrowing trouble, but I have wrapped my head around dynamically creating controls.  I am building a form on the fly that allows the user to enter as many rows of data as they wish.

I have methods for creating the controls based on a button click and am aware that as long as my controls have the same ID on each PostBack then the ViewState will populate them with the data they had before the PostBack.

My question is: Say the user has added 5 rows and filled them out. The decides to delete row 3. The easiest approach is to just call `parent.Controls.Remove("ID")`. Does this update the ViewState so that I can just decrement my counter by 1 and renumber the remaining controls from 0 to 3 or do I need to keep track of which one was deleted and keep the numbering 0, 1, 3, 4?

Do do I have to do something to clear the ViewState's record of the deleted control?

Comment: Instead of asking, you can try to do it

Comment: No problem yet. I'm wading into brand new territory for me and asked the question to gain a better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When developing an **ASP.NET Forms** application, as long as you operate within the context of the ***ASP.NET Forms*** framework and objects between *page load* and *post-backs* you will be safe. Albeit, it is sometimes challenging to do without adding custom code. Handling that in the code behind is exactly the best place for this, for adding controls dynamically to a page.

When you *remove* the control, **ViewState** should be updated automatically as you are using a *ASP.NET Forms* method directly on a control when you call `parent.Controls.Remove("ID")`. In the case you are custom naming the controls, you will need to provide all the id's or names yourself so that they are distinct for the page. So here I am under the assumption you have custom named the control, and know what to really put in place for `"ID"`.

*ViewState* is generally transparent to you as far as coding is concerned. Sometimes you may find yourself manually clearing *ViewState* between post-backs (`like for a form with a password, when every visit to the page you need to clear the value`). *ViewState* can also be turned `off`, so think about whether 
or not your app needs the extra overhead for *ViewState*. On dynamic forms, I would do my best to implement adding controls or data binding to custom data sources in the code behind. The reason being is registering client-side scripts, so **ASP.NET Forms** framework knows about the scripts, and handling a custom id attribute or naming schemes client-side can be hard to debug or deal with from a *binding* standpoint.

I have personally integrated an **ASP.NET Forms** application with *AngularJS 1.6*, and while it was more difficult, and needed more configuration than with **ASP.NET MVC**, it was still possible and offered me a nice way to build dynamic forms out of ASP.NET's hands. However, binding back to your form values in the code behind requires looking and fetching values out of `Request.Form Collection`. If done in this manner, where your form is external to *ASP.NET* there will be **no** *ViewState* for those objects.

> Does this update the ViewState so that I can just decrement my counter by 1 and renumber the remaining controls from 0 to 3 or do I need to keep track of which one was deleted and keep the numbering 0, 1, 3, 4?

As far as the strategy you are mentioning here a code sample would be most helpful. I have to make a lot of assumptions there to guess what might be happening. I could tell you it's okay, but you could still be missing something effecting the outcome in your personal results. When deleting a row, it will update the *ViewState* automatically. As far as keeping track of your numbering scheme for how you name your control Id's with distinct values, I would personally **not** leave gap's in the numbers, so stick to `0 to 3`, and it should simplify your code and you will not have to track as much in the code behind or it will not effect your rendering logic. This way the controls bind uniquely back to your code behind during a **post-back**, and you can just iterate easily through the control collections, without worrying about naming schemes as much.

Comment: thanks for the detailed discussion!  This is my first ever attempt to write an ASP.Net form from scratch, and it is from my perspective rather complex so, your discussion of the fine points above is extremely helpful!

Comment: No problem, please upvote the answer if it suits your needs. I need the experience points as my account is new :). Or let me know what I can further answer.

Comment: @cptully, if you are **new** to *ASP.NET Forms* and do not have a specific need for it or existing applications that use *ASP.NET Forms* to work on, I would spend your time learning **ASP.NET MVC** instead. Data binding to object **Models**, and not having all the *ViewState* to worry about makes a huge amount of sense compared to *Forms*. Also the industry is adopting **ASP.NET MVC**, for newer applications. *Forms* is more legacy these days.

Comment: I have studied MVC in Java using Spring so I am comfortable with MVC, but I do have a specific need for ASP.Net Forms. I have taken over maintenance of an older Forms based website. Thanks for the advice though.

Comment: said: _As far as the strategy you are mentioning here a code sample would be most helpful._ and I agree!  If I run into problems I'll post a new question with specific details of the code and the problem it is causing.