# dynamically deleting controls and their data ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

So, I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46977757/delete-dynamically-created-controls-from-the-middle-of-a-set) and got lots of helpful information that got me as far as having a page that displays. And I can dynamically create controls!  Yahoo!

I can even dynamically delete controls - sort of...

This is where things break down. Two thing happen contrary to my wishes:

1. The deleted controls stay on the page until another button is
   clicked.
2. Even though I am calling Dispose on the controls to be
   deleted, their data is still in the ViewState. So if I create five
   controls and fill in all five, then delete the third control, when
   the page does refresh, I have the data for the first four controls,
   on the first two and last two. I "loose" the data for the fifth
   control, not the third control. If i subsequently recreate a fifth
   control the fifth control's data from before is magically still
   there!

Here is my onclick handler:

```
protected void BtnDeleteRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DeleteControls(sender);
}
```

And the method it calls:

```
private void DeleteControls(object sender)
{
   Button button = (Button)sender;
   string id = button.ID;
   Panel row = (Panel)button.Parent;

   for (int i = row.Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
   {
       row.Controls[i].Dispose();
   }
   row.Parent.FindControl(row.ID).Dispose();
   if (id.Contains("Leadership"))
       NumberOfLeadershipControls--;
   else if (id.Contains("Elected"))
       NumberOfElectedControls--;
}
```

I guess I have two questions here:

1. How do I refresh the page from my event handler so that the deleted controls actually disappear from the screen?
2. How do I remove the deleted control's data from the ViewState?

Comment: Try separate your controls into update panels which may solved both problems, alternatively you may consider disabling viewstate if desired.. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx

Comment: I'm not absolutely sure what you mean by update panels... I am currently using ViewState to store the number of controls I have created, so I am reluctant to disable it. Also I have found the ViewStateModeById attribute and applied it to the class that builds the page but given that the controls I am concerned about are buried many divs deep in the page I don't think it is working for me.

Comment: Since you asking for a hack that's what I am offering. Meaning, use update panels to store viewstate there and refresh them instead the whole page.. Another idea is to convert to your controls to html like this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.aspnet/alA6R9TusTQ/LJtSrEx3QvcJ

Comment: If a hack works I'll use it but I was hoping you (or someone) would spot an error that I had made and point me to the correct way of doing things.